# What operators and statements are supported in Microsoft List conditional formulas to hide and show fields?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

There is essentially one pattern demonstrated on Microsoft's official article about this topic:

[Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#get-started-with-conditional-formulas)

Which is:

```
=if([$MyColumn] == 'Some Value', 'true', 'false')
```

We are trying to implement logic which includes `AND()`, `OR()` and `NOT()` and different operators (eg: `>=`, `<>`, `==`).

None of these seem to be working.

For example:

```
=if(AND([$MyNumberColumn] >= 1, [$MyNumberColumn] < 3), 'true', 'false')
```

just displays the error:

> Enter a valid condition

There is nothing in the Microsoft article that says these statements and operators are NOT supported, and they ARE supported in Calculated Columns, so I am at a loss as to whether there are errors in my formula OR the statements and operators I am trying to use to hide and show fields are just not supported.

Can anyone please provide an authoritative, definitive answer to the question:

What operators and statements are supported in Microsoft List conditional formulas to hide and show fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formula in below format:

**AND**: Use `&&`

```
=if([$MyNumberColumn] >= 1 && [$MyNumberColumn] < 3, 'true', 'false')
```

**OR**: Use `||`

```
=if([$MyNumberColumn] >= 1 || [$MyNumberColumn] < 3, 'true', 'false')
```

**NOT Equal**: Use `!=`

```
=if([$MyNumberColumn] != 1, 'true', 'false')
```